# What to do with highly unequal sample sizes in a dummy linear regression? (+ nonnormal distribution)

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, unbalanced-classes

I am conducting a multiple linear regression analysis in SPSS.

My DV is continuous (score between 0 and 6), and my predictors are:

- one dichotomous nominal variable (native vs. non-native speakers)
- one continuous variable (%)
- one nominal variable with 5 levels (five different countries of origin) coded as dummy variables.

The sample sizes / frequencies for three of the dummy variables are under the recommended 15% of the whole sample size (namely 12,5%, 5% and 5%). Is it a big problem? Can I correct for this with some procedure?

Moreover, in view of my pp plot / residuals histogram (see picture), I think the residuals of my data are not normally distributed. Can I correct for this with some procedure?

Many thanks in advance!
[image: residuals histogram]

Comment: Did you come up with an answer?